# Translate a regular grammar to a regular expression

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

I want to translate the following grammar into a regular expression:

- Set of variables

  *V := {S,T}*
- Set of terminals

  *Σ := {a,b}*
- Set of relations

  *S → ""*

  *S → aS*

  *S → bT*

  *T → aT*

  *T → bS*
- Start variable

  *S*

---

For the regular expression I can only use the following operations:

concatenation, union and star (no difference)

and I can use the empty word and sigma (set of all words in the alphabet).

---

I do know how to "formulate" the expression in words... but I have problems to express it in a regular expression.

Comment: What words did you produce?

Comment: In the specified language of the grammar I can produce words like _a , aba, abab_ and so on. It is important that after the first _b_ occurs, an _a_ or _b_ has to follow.

Comment: More importantly, what words can't be produced?

Comment: You say you know how to formulate the expression in words. What formulation have you deduced?

Comment: @ymbirtt a word which starts _empty_ or with any number of _a_, followed by nothing or a _b_, than an _a_ or _b_ has to follow, if an _a_ follows it can repeat it self, if a _b_ follows than it can start all over again.

Comment: @Georges, that's a very complicated way of describing this. Take a look at my hints and see how far you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINTS:**

Look at the grammar, find some stuff that you can produce, find some stuff that you can't produce. For instance, I can produce the strings $a, aa, aaa, aaaa, ...$. I can also produce the strings $bb, bab, baab, ...$. I cannot produce the strings $ab, aba, abaa, abaaa...$

Now, this is written in a way that makes it really easy to convert it into a DFA. Our two states can be labelled $S$ and $T$, and the transitions are (hopefully) fairly obvious. Look at the DFA and try and express as simply as possible what it will and will not accept before turning it into a regular expression. From there, just use the tools you have available.

**SPOILERS:**

The grammar can be represented by a DFA with state space $\{S,T\}$, accepting state $S$ and starting state $S$. On reading an $a$ we remain in our current state. On reading a $b$, we flip to the other state. The recognised language is the set of all strings containing an even number of $b$s.

The regular expression $a^*ba^*ba^*$ will recognise all strings with exactly two $b$s. The regex $(a^*ba^*ba^*)^*$ will recognise all words where the number of $b$s is a positive multiple of $2$. We can either unite or prepend this regex with $a^*$ to get the language of all words with an even number of $b$s.

Comment: Thank you for the great hint with the DFA. I did not recognize the pattern...uff